# Java LightSIDE - How to categorize data with LightSIDE?

Tags: java, plugins, machine-learning

I have set LightSIDE plugin and can run properly, but I don't know why I can't save my data to empty file? This is what a simple structure I made.

[image]

1. Activity is the list data that need to be categorize.
2. I have 3 categories and each of them have each type.
3. I already define each category with specific list of Words. For example : Food ({Sushi, Food, Japan}, {Cap Jay, Food, Chinese}, {Jog, Sport, Running}, ...)

And this is how I save my prediction with LightSIDE.

```
public void predictSectionType(String[] sections, List<String> activityList) {
        LightSideService currentLightsideHelper = new LightSideService();
        Recipe newRecipe;

        // Initialize SIDEPlugin
        currentLightsideHelper.initSIDEPlugin();

        try { 
            // Load Recipe with Extracted Features & Trained Models
            ClassLoader myClassLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            newRecipe = ConverterControl.readFromXML(new InputStreamReader(myClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("static/lightsideTrainingResult/trainingData.xml")));

            // Predict Result Data
            Recipe recipeToPredict = currentLightsideHelper.loadNewDocumentsFromCSV(sections); // DocumentList & Recipe Created
            currentLightsideHelper.predictLabels(recipeToPredict, newRecipe);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have class of LightSideService as Summary Class of LightSIDE function.

```
public class LightSideService {

    // Extract Features Parameters
    final String featureTableName = "1Grams";
    final int featureThreshold = 2;
    final String featureAnnotation = "Code";
    final Type featureType = Type.NOMINAL;

    // Build Models Parameters
    final String trainingResultName = "Bayes_1Grams";

    // Predict Labels Parameters
    final String predictionColumnName = featureAnnotation + "_Prediction";
    final boolean showMaxScore = false;
    final boolean showDists = true;
    final boolean overwrite = false;
    final boolean useEvaluation = false;

    public DocumentListTableModel model = new DocumentListTableModel(null);

    public Map<String, Serializable> validationSettings = new TreeMap<String, Serializable>();
    public Map<FeaturePlugin, Boolean> featurePlugins = new HashMap<FeaturePlugin, Boolean>();
    public Map<LearningPlugin, Boolean> learningPlugins = new HashMap<LearningPlugin, Boolean>();
    public Collection<ModelMetricPlugin> modelEvaluationPlugins = new ArrayList<ModelMetricPlugin>();
    public Map<WrapperPlugin, Boolean> wrapperPlugins = new HashMap<WrapperPlugin, Boolean>();

    // Initialize Data ==================================================

    public void initSIDEPlugin() {              
        SIDEPlugin[] featureExtractors = PluginManager.getSIDEPluginArrayByType("feature_hit_extractor");
        boolean selected = true;
        for (SIDEPlugin fe : featureExtractors) {
            featurePlugins.put((FeaturePlugin) fe, selected);
            selected = false;
        }
        SIDEPlugin[] learners = PluginManager.getSIDEPluginArrayByType("model_builder");
        for (SIDEPlugin le : learners) {
            learningPlugins.put((LearningPlugin) le, true);
        }
        SIDEPlugin[] tableEvaluations = PluginManager.getSIDEPluginArrayByType("model_evaluation");
        for (SIDEPlugin fe : tableEvaluations) {
            modelEvaluationPlugins.add((ModelMetricPlugin) fe);
        }
        SIDEPlugin[] wrappers = PluginManager.getSIDEPluginArrayByType("learning_wrapper");
        for (SIDEPlugin wr : wrappers) {
            wrapperPlugins.put((WrapperPlugin) wr, false);
        }
    }

    //Used to Train Models, adjust parameters according to model
    public void initValidationSettings(Recipe currentRecipe) {
        validationSettings.put("testRecipe", currentRecipe);
        validationSettings.put("testSet", currentRecipe.getDocumentList());
        validationSettings.put("annotation", "Age");
        validationSettings.put("type", "CV");
        validationSettings.put("foldMethod", "AUTO");
        validationSettings.put("numFolds", 10);
        validationSettings.put("source", "RANDOM");
        validationSettings.put("test", "true");
    }

    // Load CSV Doc ==================================================

    public Recipe loadNewDocumentsFromCSV(String filePath) {
        DocumentList testDocs;

        testDocs = chooseDocumentList(filePath);

        if (testDocs != null) {
            testDocs.guessTextAndAnnotationColumns();
            Recipe currentRecipe = Recipe.fetchRecipe();
            currentRecipe.setDocumentList(testDocs);
            return currentRecipe;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Recipe loadNewDocumentsFromCSV(String[] rootCauseList) {
        DocumentList testDocs;

        testDocs = chooseDocumentList(rootCauseList);

        if (testDocs != null) {
            testDocs.guessTextAndAnnotationColumns();
            Recipe currentRecipe = Recipe.fetchRecipe();
            currentRecipe.setDocumentList(testDocs);
            return currentRecipe;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected DocumentList chooseDocumentList(String filePath) {
        TreeSet<String> docNames = new TreeSet<String>();
        docNames.add(filePath);

        try {
            DocumentList testDocs;

            Charset encoding = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

            {
                testDocs = ImportController.makeDocumentList(docNames, encoding);
            }

            return testDocs;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected DocumentList chooseDocumentList(String[] rootCauseList) {
        try {
            DocumentList testDocs;

            testDocs = new DocumentList();
            testDocs.setName("TestData.csv");

            List<String> codes = new ArrayList();
            List<String> roots = new ArrayList();
            for (String s : rootCauseList) {
                codes.add("");
                roots.add((s != null) ? s : "");
            }

            testDocs.addAnnotation("Code", codes, false);
            testDocs.addAnnotation("Root Cause Failure Description", roots, false);

            return testDocs;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Save/Load XML ==================================================

    public void saveRecipeToXml(Recipe currentRecipe, String filePath) {
        File f = new File(filePath);
        try {
            ConverterControl.writeToXML(f, currentRecipe);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Recipe loadRecipeFromXml(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Recipe currentRecipe = ConverterControl.loadRecipe(filePath);
        return currentRecipe;
    }

    // Extract Features ==================================================

    public Recipe prepareBuildFeatureTable(Recipe currentRecipe) {
        // Add Feature Plugins
        Collection<FeaturePlugin> plugins = new TreeSet<FeaturePlugin>();
        for (FeaturePlugin plugin : featurePlugins.keySet()) {
            String pluginString = plugin.toString();
            if (pluginString == "Basic Features" || pluginString == "Character N-Grams") {
                plugins.add(plugin);
            }
        }

        // Generate Plugin into Recipe
        currentRecipe = Recipe.addPluginsToRecipe(currentRecipe, plugins);

        // Setup Plugin configurations
        OrderedPluginMap currentOrderedPluginMap = currentRecipe.getExtractors();
        for (SIDEPlugin plugin : currentOrderedPluginMap.keySet()) {
            String pluginString = plugin.toString();
            Map<String, String> currentConfigurations = currentOrderedPluginMap.get(plugin);

            if (pluginString == "Basic Features") {
                for (String s : currentConfigurations.keySet()) {
                    if (s == "Unigrams" || s == "Bigrams" || s == "Trigrams" ||
                        s == "Count Occurences" || s == "Normalize N-Gram Counts" || 
                        s == "Stem N-Grams" || s == "Skip Stopwords in N-Grams") {
                        currentConfigurations.put(s, "true");
                    } else {
                        currentConfigurations.put(s, "false");
                    }
                }
            } else if (pluginString == "Character N-Grams") {
                for (String s : currentConfigurations.keySet()) {
                    if (s == "Include Punctuation") {
                        currentConfigurations.put(s, "true");
                    } else if (s == "minGram") {
                        currentConfigurations.put(s, "3");
                    } else if (s == "maxGram") {
                        currentConfigurations.put(s, "4");
                    }
                }
                currentConfigurations.put("Extract Only Within Words", "true");
            }
        }

        // Build FeatureTable
        currentRecipe = buildFeatureTable(currentRecipe, featureTableName, featureThreshold, featureAnnotation, featureType);

        return currentRecipe;
    }

    protected Recipe buildFeatureTable(Recipe currentRecipe, String name,   int threshold, String annotation, Type type) {
        FeaturePlugin activeExtractor = null;

        try {
            Collection<FeatureHit> hits = new HashSet<FeatureHit>();
            for (SIDEPlugin plug : currentRecipe.getExtractors().keySet()) {
                activeExtractor = (FeaturePlugin) plug;
                hits.addAll(activeExtractor.extractFeatureHits(currentRecipe.getDocumentList(), currentRecipe.getExtractors().get(plug)));
            }

            FeatureTable ft = new FeatureTable(currentRecipe.getDocumentList(), hits, threshold, annotation, type);
            ft.setName(name);
            currentRecipe.setFeatureTable(ft);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Feature Extraction Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return currentRecipe;
    }

    // Build Models ==================================================

    public Recipe prepareBuildModel(Recipe currentRecipe) {
        try {
            // Get Learner Plugins
            LearningPlugin learner = null;
            for (LearningPlugin plugin : learningPlugins.keySet()) {
                /* if (plugin.toString() == "Naive Bayes") */
                if (plugin.toString() == "Logistic Regression") {
                    learner = plugin;
                }
            }

            if (Boolean.TRUE.toString().equals(validationSettings.get("test"))) {
                if (validationSettings.get("type").equals("CV")) {
                    validationSettings.put("testSet", currentRecipe.getDocumentList());
                }
            }

            Map<String, String> settings = learner.generateConfigurationSettings();

            currentRecipe = Recipe.addLearnerToRecipe(currentRecipe, learner, settings);
            currentRecipe.setValidationSettings(new TreeMap<String, Serializable>(validationSettings));

            for (WrapperPlugin wrap : wrapperPlugins.keySet()) {
                if (wrapperPlugins.get(wrap)) {
                    currentRecipe.addWrapper(wrap, wrap.generateConfigurationSettings());
                }
            }

            buildModel(currentRecipe, validationSettings);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return currentRecipe;
    }

    protected void buildModel(Recipe currentRecipe,
            Map<String, Serializable> validationSettings) {
        try {
            FeatureTable currentFeatureTable = currentRecipe.getTrainingTable();
            if (currentRecipe != null) {
                TrainingResult results = null;
                /*
                 * if (validationSettings.get("type").equals("SUPPLY")) {
                 * DocumentList test = (DocumentList)
                 * validationSettings.get("testSet"); FeatureTable
                 * extractTestFeatures = prepareTestFeatureTable(currentRecipe,
                 * validationSettings, test);
                 * validationSettings.put("testFeatureTable",
                 * extractTestFeatures);
                 * 
                 * // if we've already trained the exact same model, don't // do
                 * it again. Just evaluate. Recipe cached =
                 * checkForCachedModel(); if (cached != null) { results =
                 * evaluateUsingCachedModel(currentFeatureTable,
                 * extractTestFeatures, cached, currentRecipe); } }
                 */

                if (results == null) {
                    results = currentRecipe.getLearner().train(currentFeatureTable, currentRecipe.getLearnerSettings(), validationSettings, currentRecipe.getWrappers());
                }

                if (results != null) {
                    currentRecipe.setTrainingResult(results);
                    results.setName(trainingResultName);

                    currentRecipe.setLearnerSettings(currentRecipe.getLearner().generateConfigurationSettings());
                    currentRecipe.setValidationSettings(new TreeMap<String, Serializable>(validationSettings));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected static FeatureTable prepareTestFeatureTable(Recipe recipe, Map<String, Serializable> validationSettings, DocumentList test) {
        prepareDocuments(recipe, validationSettings, test); // assigns classes, annotations.

        Collection<FeatureHit> hits = new TreeSet<FeatureHit>();
        OrderedPluginMap extractors = recipe.getExtractors();
        for (SIDEPlugin plug : extractors.keySet()) {
            Collection<FeatureHit> extractorHits = ((FeaturePlugin) plug).extractFeatureHits(test, extractors.get(plug));
            hits.addAll(extractorHits);
        }
        FeatureTable originalTable = recipe.getTrainingTable();
        FeatureTable ft = new FeatureTable(test, hits, 0, originalTable.getAnnotation(), originalTable.getClassValueType());
        for (SIDEPlugin plug : recipe.getFilters().keySet()) {
            ft = ((RestructurePlugin) plug).filterTestSet(originalTable, ft, recipe.getFilters().get(plug), recipe.getFilteredTable().getThreshold());
        }

        ft.reconcileFeatures(originalTable.getFeatureSet());

        return ft;

    }

    protected static Map<String, Serializable> prepareDocuments(Recipe currentRecipe, Map<String, Serializable> validationSettings, DocumentList test) throws IllegalStateException {
        DocumentList train = currentRecipe.getDocumentList();

        try {
            test.setCurrentAnnotation(currentRecipe.getTrainingTable().getAnnotation(), currentRecipe.getTrainingTable().getClassValueType());
            test.setTextColumns(new HashSet<String>(train.getTextColumns()));
            test.setDifferentiateTextColumns(train.getTextColumnsAreDifferentiated());

            Collection<String> trainColumns = train.allAnnotations().keySet();
            Collection<String> testColumns = test.allAnnotations().keySet();
            if (!testColumns.containsAll(trainColumns)) {
                ArrayList<String> missing = new ArrayList<String>(trainColumns);
                missing.removeAll(testColumns);
                throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException("Test set annotations do not match training set.\nMissing columns: " + missing);
            }

            validationSettings.put("testSet", test);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException("Could not prepare test set.\n" + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return validationSettings;
    }

    //Predict Labels ==================================================

    public void predictLabels(Recipe recipeToPredict, Recipe currentRecipe) {
        DocumentList newDocs = null;
        DocumentList originalDocs;
        if (useEvaluation) {
            originalDocs = recipeToPredict.getTrainingResult().getEvaluationTable().getDocumentList();

            TrainingResult results = currentRecipe.getTrainingResult();
            List<String> predictions = (List<String>) results.getPredictions();
            newDocs = addLabelsToDocs(predictionColumnName, showDists, overwrite, originalDocs, results, predictions, currentRecipe.getTrainingTable());
        } else {
            originalDocs = recipeToPredict.getDocumentList();

            Predictor predictor = new Predictor(currentRecipe, predictionColumnName);
            newDocs = predictor.predict(originalDocs, predictionColumnName, showDists, overwrite);
        }

        // Predict Labels result
        model.setDocumentList(newDocs);
    }

    protected DocumentList addLabelsToDocs(final String name, final boolean showDists, final boolean overwrite, DocumentList docs, TrainingResult results, List<String> predictions, FeatureTable currentFeatureTable) {
        Map<String, List<Double>> distributions = results.getDistributions();
        DocumentList newDocs = docs.clone();
        newDocs.addAnnotation(name, predictions, overwrite);
        if (distributions != null) {
            if (showDists) {
                for (String label : currentFeatureTable.getLabelArray()) {
                    List<String> dist = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < predictions.size(); i++) {
                        dist.add(String.format("%.3f", distributions.get(label).get(i)));
                    }

                    newDocs.addAnnotation(name + "_" + label + "_score", dist, overwrite);
                }
            }
        }
        return newDocs;
    }

    // ==================================================
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David. It looks like the above replicates a lot of the functionality from the `edu.cmu.side.recipe` package. However, it doesn't look like your `predictSectionType()` method actually outputs the model's predictions anywhere.

If what you're trying to do is indeed to save predictions on new data using a trained model, check out the `edu.cmu.side.recipe.Predictor` class. It takes a trained model path as input, It's used by the `scripts/predict.sh` convenience script, but you could repurpose its main method if you needed to call it programmatically.

I hope this helps!

Comment: After tracing all the code, i just notice i didn't create Trained model first. Thank you. I'll check it first

Comment: The problem is, I don't have trained model, and its the reason why its always error.